# Transmission voltage

Tags: voltage, electrical-engineering

I don't understand how to calculate transmission voltages I thought you needed the length of the lines to do it but I haven't been given one.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/z3lHH.jpg

Comment: If the problem gave you the line length, what would you do with it exactly?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are told that the resistance of the lines is $R=50\Omega$, which I assume is the resistance over their whole length.

You are given power ($P$) that the customer uses and the voltage that they see.  From $P=IV$ you can calculate current.

Current in the line is the same as the current the customer sees.  Voltage the customer sees is not the same as the voltage drop from one end of the line to the other.  But you can calculate the voltage drop along the line once you know current and resistance ($V=IR$).

Disclaimer: I don't know anything about HV transmission.  This is just basic circuit theory.

Comment: so the current would be the same for all three tables ?

Comment: @Michaelscott. I have edited my post to hopefully make it clearer.  You will use the voltages in the table (and the power for the relevant customer) and get a different value for current in each cell.  You can use that current, and $R$, to work out power dissipated in the line.

Comment: thanks for the help i think i get it now :)